# Creating a procedure for creating a table with dynamic number of columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a procedure that can create a table with not specific number of columns.
My query returns a value of 3 meaning it needs 3 columns (has to be dynamic).

I have create a `@variable` to set the name string of the tables but I don't know how to formulate the `CREATE TABLE` statement to actually create the table with the columns from this string.

Any kind of help would be appreciated guys.

Comment: have u got any help, i have also the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the columns on a table out of the sql database with

```
select 

    bb.name,
    bb.colid

from sysobjects aa
inner join syscolumns bb
on aa.id = bb.id
where aa.name ='tblMyTable'
```

The name is the column name, the ID the number. You could select column names from the list and use dynamic sql to build a select. Not sure how you decide what columns you are after from the table.

Comment: Hi,, Thanks, but i knew how to find the column names, the issue is how to create a table using these names? The problem is that the number of columns change, that's why is has to by able to create the table with dynamic number of columns. The names are not really that big of an issue

Comment: You will need to use dynamic SQL; there are lots of examples on stack for that already.